# How to prevent unit test from using util from test project?

Tags: java, eclipse, unit-testing

I am using eclipse and I have two projects, project1 and project1-test. Below is the example layout of my projects:

```
project1  
-src  
--my.package  
----MyClass.java  
--my.package.util  
----util.java  

project1-test  
-src  
--my.package  
----MyClassTest.java  
--my.package.util  
----util.java
```

MyClass.java makes a static call to the util.java in project1. MyClassTests.java is testing MyClass.java. When the test class runs, it fails and complains that MyClass.java is referencing a method in util.java that doesn't exist. Under project1, the method being referenced exists in util.java but under project1-test, the method doesn't.

When I run MyClassTests.java, the util.java that is being referenced from MyClass.java is from project1-test when it should be project1. Is there some way to make MyClass.java not reference util.java from project1-test when running MyClassTest.java?

Comment: I would recommend to move test **util** class to specific tests package. Otherwise you have to play tricky game with classloader

Comment: Either name your test util differently e.g. UtilTest or use the fully qualified name.

Comment: @Bart I think in this case both the util.java classes will have the same qualified name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a classpath problem. You have a class called `my.package.util.util` in both projects, and when you are running code in `project1-test` it is placed on the classpath first by Eclipse.

You easiest solution would be to rename the `util` class in your test project. Or even just put it in a different package.

Another solution would be to manipulate the classpath that Eclipse is using, but that would mean always using classes from `project1` before those in `project1-test`.

Comment: Thanks cneff! I don't want to mess with classpaths so I'll probably end up changing the name or package. I did have the tests in project1, going back to that may be another option.